# How to scale and rotate a view in a single animation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, rotation, scale

I am trying to present a view by making it emerge from the centre of the screen while growing to its full size, while also rotating it around the x-axis in a 3D manner. When I create the view I apply a transform to it to make sure it is shrunk and rotated to start off with (it is so small it is not actually visible), then I try to use a CATransform3D like this:

```
CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DRotate(view.layer.transform, M_PI, 1.0, 0, 0);
transform = CATransform3DScale(transform, 1000, 1000, 1000);
transform.m34 = 1.0 / 10000;
[anim setToValue:[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform]];
[anim setDuration:0.75f];
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anim.delegate = self;
[view.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"grow"];
```

However this animation does not change the actual transform of the layer, so I also do this:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)theAnimation finished:(BOOL)flag {
    view.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    [view.layer removeAllAnimations];
}
```

to set the transform once the animation stops. However this sometimes results in a noticeable flicker at the end of the animation. I believe this is because the animation puts the original transform back at the end of the animation phase and this happens momentarily before the animationDidStop routine gets called. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: Incorporating it into a UIView animation works as this way you can set the transform directly:

```
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001);
view.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(view.layer.transform, M_PI, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DRotate(view.layer.transform, M_PI, 1.0, 0, 0);
transform = CATransform3DScale(rotationTransform, 1000, 1000, 1000);
transform.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
view.layer.transform = transform;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

However, I would still like an answer to my original query, as to how to achieve the same successully using a CAAnimation, as that provides more flexibility for animations generally.

Edit2: It seems the answer to my original question (how to fix the problem with the CAAnimation) was actually very straightforward. To keep the end state (and remove the flicker), I just needed to add the following line:

```
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
```

Comment: Nope, its set to YES on the layer being animated.

Comment: Unfortunately, it made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

```
  animationView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.0f, 0.0f);

  animationView.center = CGPointMake(0, 
                                  (animationView.center.y - 
                                   (animationView.bounds.size.height/2.0f)));

  // start the Page Open
  [UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation" context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];     
  // set angle as per requirement
  [animationView.layer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:180] 
                  forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];

  [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that achieves what I am after. I know that leaves the transform in place when the animation completes, but it does not allow for the scaling, or most importantly the perspective you get from using the CATransform3D.

Comment: Ok, I placed my whole transform inside the UIView animation, `view.layer.transform = transform;`, and that did the trick. Thanks for the pointer. I thought you had to use a CAAnimation to do layer animations, but seems I was wrong.

Comment: However, I would still be interested to know how to get around the problem using the CABasicAnimation :)

Comment: Welcome.. Can you please add the solution with the question so that it would be useful for others too. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a clean and short answer you were probably hoping for :)

But here ([UIView Animation Tutorial: Practical Recipes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes)
) you can find a downloadable example which also shows how to do scale & rotate.

You can see the scale and rotate if you run the example, click HUD and then click stop.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I like the 'drain' animation, have incorporated that already ;). It also gave some other useful pointers.

Answer (score 0):

See this thread about how iPad app store does the rotate and scale for an answer and code : [How can I flip and enlarge a UIView it at the same time like iOS 7 iPad App Store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171918/how-can-i-flip-and-enlarge-a-uiview-it-at-the-same-time-like-ios-7-ipad-app-stor)