# Flash/flicker UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uiviewanimation

I need to give some stretch & skew animation to a `UIView` upon pressing a button or completion of a task.

Most of the animation applied to `UIView` are usually applied when they are added to or removed from a `UIView` but how can I accomplish that with a view already added to view.

Animation could be anything as long as it catches users attention (to indicate that the task was completed).

Comment: So is it stretch&skew or flash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** [How to scale and rotate a view in a single animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341332/how-to-scale-and-rotate-a-view-in-a-single-animation)

You might need use Core Animation and add both animations in a group:

```
CABasicAnimation *stetchAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.scale.x"];
stetchAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:(someView.frame.size.width+100)/someView.frame.size.width];

CABasicAnimation *skewAnimation = CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.x"];
stetchAnimation.toValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:180];

//Add both animation at time when task is completed

CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animationGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stetchAnimation,skewAnimation,nil];
animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = YES;
animationGroup.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
animationGroup.duration = 0.7; // increase duration if needed

[someView.layer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:@"animations"];
```

Comment: when last line is executed i.e. animation is added to layer, will the view start animating or do I have to do something else too .. ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9341332/how-to-scale-and-rotate-a-view-in-a-single-animation

Answer (score 1):

Simple UIView animation; temporarily grows the view:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    CGRect frm = view.frame;
    frm.size.width += 20;
    frm.size.height += 20;
    frm.origin.x -= 10;
    frm.origin.y -= 10;
    view.frame = frm;
} completion:^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect frm = view.frame;
        frm.size.width -= 20;
        frm.size.height -= 20;
        frm.origin.x += 10;
        frm.origin.y += 10;
        view.frame = frm;
    }];
}];
```